# vmoptions classpath with non-ascii characters

Tags: install4j

I'm adding the following line `-classpath/p ${installer:sys.userHome}/.comput/updates/latest.jar` to the `vmoption` file. (Tried both options: via installer 'Add VM option' action and via launcher config).

Works pretty fine with ASCII user name (with spaces as well), but fails with non-ascii user names (I'm testing with Russian). The vmoption file looks fine to me: the path is correct and has the right encoding: CP 1251 for my case:

[image]

However the path passed to JVM seems to have incorrectly decoded characters: On the attached screen you may see the actual path passed to JVM (checked via YourKit) from Install4J launcher:

[image]

and you may also compare it with the screen when the non-ascii path is passed via command prompt:

[image]

The only workaround I have found is to substitute the path with 8.3 Windows path, but converting to it on pure Java seems very error prone to me.

Appeciate your help very much!

Comment: What is your system encoding (output of `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`)? Please try to set the path with `${USERPROFILE}` in the .vmoptions file instead of modifying the path with the actual value at runtime. Does it work then?

Comment: @IngoKegel Wow! That works! Thanks a lot for prompt response! (as well for other SO topics regarding i4j)
FYI: here are some related stystem properties from the app:
`file.encoding=Cp1251`

`install4j.appDir=C:\Program Files\Computta`

`java.class.path=C:\Users\Aioii I\.computta\computta.0.79.jar;C:\Program Files\Computta\.install4j\i4jruntime.jar;C:\Program Files\Computta\.\yuan-client-all.jar`